# External Service error Map data type isn't supported.: Schema

Tags: external-services

I am trying to add fixer.io currency convert as an External Service.
When I am pasting the Service Schema Complete JSON I get the following error

> Map data type isn't supported.: Schema

What is the workaround for this?
Can I change the Schema JSON in some way to not include a Map?

Answer (score 0):

Schema is a reserved type. You should change the type to another type and try that.

Comment: the type which isn't supported is Map and the issue is how to work around it

Comment: can you  update your post to show its usage please. I can do better with more information.